# PHPUnit and Symfony

Tags: html, symfony, phpunit

i'm trying to test my indexAction method, just to test if there's some precise words in it my page.

So I have this

```
public function testIndexAction()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'conducteurs');
    $this->assertSame(1, $crawler->filter('html:contains("Liste des conducteurs")')->count());
}
```

In my page, there is "Liste des conducteurs", but my test is failing. Do you know why ? Is there a precise setup for the phpunit.xml ?

Comment: Maybe you missed leading slash? `$client->request('GET', '/conducteurs');` ?

Comment: I tried with and without, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Probably the string appears more than one time.
You can change the assert to

```
$this->assertGreaterThan(0,$crawler->filter('html:contains("Liste des conducteurs")')->count());
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but no, there only 1 string like that. And if I try another word (which doesn't exist like "bonjoru") it's not working either

Answer (score 0):

I can't possibly guess what's going on with your app as I haven't seen it. What I can do, however, is to suggest how you could debug it and improve your tests to give you better feedback.

Before you start looking into the response content you could make sure that the response was successful. You could also use the response content as an assertion message, so phpunit would display the content if the assertion fails.

```php
public function testIndexAction()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'conducteurs');

    $this->assertSame(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), $client->getResponse()->getContent());
    $this->assertSame(1, $crawler->filter('html:contains("Liste des conducteurs")')->count(), $client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```

If the status code is not a 200, but not an error either, it could be that your site makes a redirect (301/302), in which case you can either [follow all redirects](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#redirecting) automatically:

```php
$client->followRedirects();
```

or follow that specific redirect:

```php
$crawler = $client->followRedirect();
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but the code 200 isn't working. It's working with 302 (or 301 i don't remembrer) even if there is not redirect on this page, the code on symfony debug toolbar is 200

Comment: That's because your browser did the redirect automatically. Tests won't do that unless you tell 'em so. Updated my answer to hint you how to handle it.